# Rails 5 ranking of users by number of tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have 2 models User and Task

```
User -> has_many :tasks
Task -> belongs_to :user
```

I want to make a ranking of users by number of tasks

Expected output:

```
[['jhon', 120],['peter', 115],['mary', 101],....]
```

my attempt:

```
User.left_joins(:tasks).group(:id).order('count(tasks.id)').limit(20) ---> not working, can't get the user name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query to

```
User.left_joins(:tasks).group(:id).select('users.name, count(tasks.id) as tasks_count').order('tasks_count DESC').limit(20).map{ |user| [user.name, user.tasks_count] }
```